# Data view don't show the index of DataFrame neither rows numbers from numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pycharm

I am using Pycharm Community Edition 2017.1 and when I try to see a DataFrame or a numpy array, the "data view" does not show the rows index neither the rows numbers, respectively. See attached an example with DataFrame. What am I missing?

[image]

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
var = np.arange(3*2).reshape((3,2))
fr = pd.DataFrame(var, columns=['a','b'], index=range(np.shape(var)[0]))
fr
Out[6]: 
   a  b
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
```

I really appreciate help.

Alexandre

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose showing the row numbers or `index` is a feature which is supported in Linux and Mac platform, it works well on my MacBook.

[image]

From [Viewing as Array or DataFrame](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/viewing-as-array-or-dataframe.html) and [Pandas Dataframes Viewer](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/06/pycharm-2016-2-eap-2-build-162-917/) , I suppose this feature has not been supported in Windows yet.

---

**Update**

PyCharm 2017.1.3 (**May 4, 2017**)  RC fix this issue,
See 
[PyCharm 171.4249.61 Release Notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/PyCharm+171.4249.61+Release+Notes).

Comment: McGrady, thanks. Maybe the operational system is the problem. I have to change to other system :-).

Comment: It was supported on Windows in the last version of pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

This is a defect in 2017.2:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23419

fixed in 2017.3